# AJAX call a function with a parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

The following gives me a internal server error.

```
var jsonStateData;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions.aspx/StateSalesDataString",
        data: '{' + 'AL' + '}',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            jsonStateData = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        }
    }).done(function () {
        console.log(jsonStateData);

    })
```

This is the function that it is calling

```
//Returns stores sales datatable
[WebMethod]
public static string StateSalesDataString(string whichState)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dashboard_VWConnectionStringTest"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    string storeSalesQuery = "SELECT StoreSalesTbl.StoreNumb, Lat, Lng, TodayTotalSales, TodayTotalOrders, TodayTotalWebSales, TodayTotalCallSales, TodayTotalIFSales, TodayTotalStoreSales, TodayTotalWebOrders, TodayTotalCallOrders, TodayTotalIFOrders, TodayTotalStoreOrders " +
                             "From StoreSalesTbl INNER JOIN StoreAddreTbl " +
                             "ON StoreSalesTbl.StoreID = StoreAddreTbl.StoreID " +
                             "Where DatetimeTo IN (SELECT max(DatetimeTo) FROM StoreSalesTbl) " +
                             "AND StoreAddreTbl.State = @stateName";

    SqlCommand storeComm = new SqlCommand(storeSalesQuery, conn);
    storeComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateName", whichState);

    storeComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    // Create a DataAdapter to run the command and fill the DataTable
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dataAdpt.SelectCommand = storeComm;
    DataTable storeDataTbl = new DataTable();
    dataAdpt.Fill(storeDataTbl);

    conn.Close();

    //convert the datatable to string
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach (DataRow dr in storeDataTbl.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in storeDataTbl.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

UPDATE
Thank you guys for answering! I think my problem might also be in my c# function. Am I doing anything wrong with the query statement @stateName part?

Because when I changed the query's last line to just

```
AND StoreAddreTbl.State = 'AL'"
```

It worked. But when I pass the string whichState in there, it didn't proceed.

Comment: What is that string you're sending in `data` supposed to represent? [jQuery `.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) expect `data` to either be a true object or a query string.

Comment: Does your method (*StateSalesDataString*) accept xml/soap or json?

Comment: `StateSalesDataString` isn't returning a string

Comment: Thank you all for responding. I have copied and pasted all my code for StateSalesDataString. I think the query might be what is causing the problem.

Comment: @vincwng - Not a problem! Consider accepting my answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. You have it looking like this:

```
{'AL'}
```

It should be looking similar to this:

```
{ "whichState": "AL" }
```

The proper way to do this in JavaScript:

```
var myData = {};
myData.whichState = 'AL';

var jsonStateData;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions.aspx/StateSalesDataString",
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            jsonStateData = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        }
    }).done(function () {
        console.log(jsonStateData);

    })
```

Notice on the `data` parameter, I'm using `JSON.stringify`. The JavaScript [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function will automatically create your JSON string for you.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I think there might be problem with my query paremeter passing. I have pasted my entire function there. Could you take a look of it?

Comment: @VincentWang - Put a breakpoint in there and look at the value of `whichState`. Make sure it is `AL` as expected.

Comment: @vincwng  BTW: No need for *JSON.stringify*. `data: myData` is enough. *ajax* request will do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When sending the data, give it the key you expect to assign it to. For example, you should be able to do:

```
data: { "whichState" : "AL" }
```